# What type of capacitor is this and ...?

Tags: voltage, capacitor

[image]
From the pics I saw in some websites and from what I read so far I can assume that it is a film capacitor, but I am confused. I would appreciate it if someone told me what type of capacitor is this :

http://s23.postimg.org/3kmxdurtn/20131123_020105.jpg 
http://s7.postimg.org/nqz2l825n/20131123_020027.jpg

and can I replace it with electrolytic or ceramic ones? And what about the voltage since there isn't any description on it, there are some other electrolytic capacitors  with these volatages: 6.3 V, 16 V, 25 V on the same board. I found that 333K means that the capacity is 33nF.It is on a board of a Netgear DG834GT router, the output from the power adapter is 12 V , 1.0 A.

P.S. The power adapter is OK. I tested all capacitors in the board, others were okay and that one didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the proximity of gas tube surge suppressor, ethernet transformer and RJ45 are clear to me this must be a. Film cap with 100R load in parallel.   I doubt it is bad.

Comment: Yes it is parallel and it didn't pass through my mind. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a 33nF Capacitor: http://www.csgnetwork.com/capcodeinfo.html

And you should be able to replace it with a ceramic one with similar characteristics, just make sure to select one with enough voltage overhead.

Electrolytic capacitors do have better performance but they come at a higher price, and at that power stage you won't require such thing.
I refer to this Application Note when I have that kind of doubts: http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an13/an1325.pdf